# Sort a list containing alphanumeric values with specific format

Tags: python

I have a list that consists of details like this:

```
['00A', '01B', '05A', '00A', '23C', '00B']
```

I want to sort this list, such that the values are in the following order:

```
['00A', '00A', '05A', '00B', '01B', '23C']
```

I tried with different methods,

```
sorted(a, key = lambda x: (isinstance(x, str), x))
```

but doesn't give the correct answer - it gives:

```
['00A', '00A', '00B', '01B', '05A', '23C']
```

So i want to sort them based on their end position alpha value FIRST, and then the leading numeric values that follows the number.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you always have two numbers followed by one letter you were almost there:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[2], x[:2]))
```

if they are more complex (variable length) you might find regexes useful like so:

```
import re
sorted(l, key=lambda x: re.search("^(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)$", x).group(2, 1))
```

Comment: Hi Schorsch, Thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are irregular (variable amount of digits and letters), you could build a sort key formed of the non-digit part, by stripping the prefix, followed by the right justified and zero filled string (to get numerical order):

```
L = ['00A', '00A', '05A', '00B', '01B', '23C']

sorted(L,key=lambda s: [s.lstrip("0123456789"),s.rjust(5,"0")])

['00A', '00A', '05A', '00B', '01B', '23C']
```